# Connect host to virtualbox virtually via usb

Tags: usb, virtualbox, connection

I have Windows 7 and let's say I want to set up another Windows 7 in VirtualBox. Is there a way to somehow connect both the host and VirtualBox client via a virtual USB or something without any cables etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The Virtualbox manual explains in considerable detail how to use Shared folders.

Windows 7 allows folders to be shared over the network.  Virtualbox guest and host to be on the same subnet via Bridged adapters.

USB would seem to be a really hard way of approaching the problem.

Good luck.